# How to Handle pop up window with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to programming and am trying to automate a process of my business that needs to be performed once weekly.  I am using selenium and can get my way all the way to the pop up window and am using .keys to click on buttons.  Once I click on the button in the pop up window, the information populates, but I cant seem to parse out the info from there.  The information shows when I inspect, but when I try to call on and extract the info it says element not found.  I have done a ton of internet research to try to figure this out myself but can't seem to find the correct answer.  Iframes doesn't seem to work either.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

```
<div data-v-bbef4c82="" class="text-left col col-12"> Created: 351 <br data-v-bbef4c82=""> Received: 351 <br data-v-bbef4c82=""> Completed: 269 <br data-v-bbef4c82=""> Closed: 309 <br data-v-bbef4c82=""> Invoiced: 321 <br data-v-bbef4c82=""></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a time delay before you look for the element? It sometimes takes a second to load. Add a time.sleep(2) before you look for the element. Might help

Comment: Also can you post the code you wrote?

Comment: yes, but still received the error.....

Comment: drpdwn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "v-select__slot")
    drpdwn.click()
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN * 3)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()
    actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN * 3)
    actions.perform()
    actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 12)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(2)
    actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_UP).perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Created")

Comment: And its a link for sure? Its hard for us to troubleshoot unless we have something that we can reproduce ourselves. Eg. a link to inspect the HTML and full code that doesn't work etc. If the program cannot find the element, there is either something wrong with your search or the browser hasn't loaded the element yet. Try searching a different way like with XPath. That's my go-to

Comment: Yeah, the page is behind a login and password for my company so I am not sure I want to give out the credentials in order to reproduce.  I do have screen shots if that helps?

Comment: Basically, I navigate to a page from the home page.  Click a link named "quick status summary", once I click that, it pulls up a pop up window where I click a dropdown, choose "this month", then click a button named skip details.  Once I click that, the info is populated that I need.  Once I am there, I click inspect and the info is there, but i cant extract for some reason.

Comment: also, every time I have tried to use xpath, I get a syntax error talking about maybe I needed a comma.  Not sure what thats about

Comment: Hey did you solve the issue you were having?

Comment: I did not......